# How to get index of item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a index of  items to the left,  right, bottom, and top of a binary integer in a 4x4 grid. With what I am doing now doesn't seem to be getting the correct index of a value.

```
        if self.data[index] == 1:
            self.data[index] = 0
                if self.data.index(self.data[index]) - 1 >= 0:
                    print("Left toggled")
                    if self.data[index - 1] == 1:
                        self.data[index - 1] = 0
                    else:
                        self.data[index - 1] = 1
```

As of now I am trying with the bit array of `010011100100` which is returning a -1 if `index = 5` in the above code example when it should be returning 4 as 5-1=4.

I assume my if statement `if self.data.index(self.data[index]) - 1 >= 0:` is wrong, but I am unsure of the syntax of what I am trying to accompish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets step through your code and see what happens...

```
#We'll fake these in so the code makes sence...
#self.data must be an array as you can't reassign as you are doing later
self.data = list("010011100100")
index = 5

if self.data[index] == 1:      # Triggered, as self.data[:5] is  "010011"
    self.data[index] = 0       # AHA self.data is now changed to "010010..."!!!
        if self.data.index(self.data[index]) - 1 >= 0:
           #Trimmed
```

In the second last line you are getting `self.data[index]` which is now `0` as we changed it the line before.

But also, remember that **[`Array.index()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)** returns the first instance of that item in the array. So `self.data.index(0)` returns the first instance of `0`, which is the first or more precicely, zeroth element. Thus is `self.data.index(0)` gives `0` and `0-1` is... `-1`.

As for what your code *should* be, that is a tougher answer.

I think your conditional may just be:

```
width  = 4 # For a 4x4 grid, defined much earlier.
height = 4 # For a 4x4 grid, defined much earlier.

...

if index%width == 0:
    print "we are on the left edge"
if index%width == width - 1:
    print "we are on the right edge"
if index%height == 0:
    print "we are on the top edge"
if index%height == height - 1:
    print "we are on the bottom edge"
```

Comment: Yeah that's about how far I figured it. What I am trying to essentially do is change the forth index accordingly instead of doing math on the values inside the indexes.

Comment: @BobDunakey Forth index, you mean fourth?

Comment: @LegoStromtrooper yeah typo.

Comment: @LegoStromtrooper I was able to work out a similar solution thanks for suggestion it really helped.
P.S. The solution was I just used the index value I was pulling into the function (doh, I was trying to be complex when a simple solution was in front of me) so I was able to do 5-1<=0.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I'm pretty sure you mean the Force Index.  Dunno what it is, but I'm guessing it's like some Midichlorian count or something

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee That was a type, I actually meant the *Forbes index* where you can see how expensive a given element in an array is.